# What's better for identification: retina scanner or iris scanner?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction

A retinal scanner or an iris scanner. I know it's equivalent to Coke vs Pepsi, but I want my sci fi world to be as technologically advanced as possible

Comment: Sci-Fi world? Use both at once then.

Comment: This is actually quite a lot more difficult of a question than you might think at first.  There are *many* tradeoffs to both technologies.  I recommend doing a google search for "retinal scanner vs iris scanner" and doing some basic research.  For example, the top hit when I do that is "[Iris Scanning vs. Retina Scanning -- What are the differences](http://www.m2sys.com/blog/biometric-hardware/iris-recognition-vs-retina-scanning-what-are-the-differences/)".  It is very likely that that blog answers your question.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Are you asking which is more scifi-esque or are you looking for the more practical option?

Comment: Diabetic retinopathy is a fairly common condition that would affect how well retina scanners work. Around 40-45% of diabetic patients have a degree of retinopathy and  around 10% of the population of America is diabetic. the disease it's self causes blockages in the bloo vessels, leakages and the growth of new vessels, and even blindness.

Comment: use both and that will be more technologically advanced. Also do not forget DNA

Comment: Define your "better", please.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what exactly you are trying to do, each technology has its advantages and disadvantages.

For ubiquitous surveillance and security, iris scanning is best. Cameras placed in every location can "see" people as they pass and use iris scanning (and possibly other methodology like facial recognition) to identify individuals as they pass by the camera. This is a rather nightmarish scenario if you are living in a dystopian "1984" like environment, but even in a normal capitalistic environment you could imagine advertisers or busybodies like Facebook monitoring your locations and building up profiles of your activities in order to either target you with advertising or sell your profile to the highest bidder (why do you think you don't pay a subscription to Facebook?)

Iris scanning would also be preferable in most consumer goods, since it is unobtrusive. Walking into your room, your devices would "see" you and instantly identify you and (for example) log you into your laptop or start your car in the garage. People would appreciate the flexibility of simply glancing at their own consumer goods to unlock the functionality of them.

Retina scanners, because they are more obtrusive, are preferred for higher levels of security. Since you must place your face into a scanning device to you eye will be in the proper register for the device to function, there is clear intent on your part to enter the secure zone or use the secure device. No one is "accidentally" trying to enter the SCIF or arm the nuclear warhead, for example. This also deters casual attempts to hack or compromise the facility, since the person is easily contained. You would first have to enter the facility's outer region (perhaps via iris scanner), then move through the facility to the level 2 or level 3 secure areas. The retina scanner in movies is always in the hallway right outside the door, but practically would more likely be in a "phone booth" enclosure, and failure to pass the scan would lock the doors until security arrives.

So you can use either technology, but be aware of the limitations and how they would affect how the people installing the technology would plan to use it.

Answer (score 0):

From literature [(e.g.)](http://www.m2sys.com/blog/iris-recognition-2/difference-iris-retina-important-biometric-identification/?utm_source=blog&utm_medium=blog%20post&utm_campaign=iris%20retina%20difference) it seems they give similar results, but iris scan is less intrusive and retina scan can be hampered by several (very common) diseases.

I would go for iris scan.